# Python CSV file: print missing elements compared to list. Prints entire column

Tags: python, csv, import, printing

I am trying to check the column headers of the CSV file with a pre-defined list. If there is one missing, I want to print that element. Thus far I have this"

```
#import modules
import csv
from csv import reader

#set CSV file name
file_name = 'check.csv'


#declaring the error count variable starting at 0.
errors = 0


check = ['CLIENT', 'DATE_FROM', 'DATE_TO', 'NATION', 'PERSNUMBER', 'NAME_TEXT']


#open the CSV file
with open(file_name) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ';')

    limit = 0
    for header in reader:
        if limit == 1:
            break
        else:
            if header not in check:
                print("Unrecognised column", header)
                errors += 1
            else:
                pass
        limit += 1

print('Header validation finished.')
if errors == 0:
    print('No missing or odd headers')
else:
    print(errors, 'errors encountered.' )
```

The output is this:

```
Unrecognised column ['CLIENT', 'DATE_FROM', 'PERSNUMBER', 'DATE_TO', 'NATION', 'NAME_TEXT', 'SLT_SYSID']
```

The CSV file contains all these columns, but the 'SLT_SYSID' is "extra'. Nevertheless, it prints the entire row, instead of just the missing value.

Whenever I run a test script like this:

```
item = ['Cheese','Cake',0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
z = [0, 'Cheese']

for element in item:
    if element not in z:
        print(element)
```

Output:

```
Cake
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

It works fine. I am thinking it has to do something with reading the CSV file?

Any tips or suggestions are welcome.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sets here. You can make `check` a set instead of a list and then you only read the first row of the file and convert that to a set to enable easy comparisons, eg:

```
import csv

file_name = 'check.csv'
check = {'CLIENT', 'DATE_FROM', 'DATE_TO', 'NATION', 'PERSNUMBER', 'NAME_TEXT'}

with open(file_name) as fin:
    csvin = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=';')
    header = set(next(csvin, set()))
```

You can then check if what you're expecting is what's present:

```
if check == header:
    print('ok!')
```

Otherwise, you can take the difference between what you're expecting and what you have and its inverse and print those out, eg:

```
else:
    missing = check - header
    extra = header - check
    print('missing ({}):'.format(len(missing)), missing)
    print('extra ({}):'.format(len(extra)), extra)
```